# How long does it take to domesticate animals?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How long does it take for a trainer to domesticate a giant cave spider and a hydra? I have them both restrained with a chain over an animal training zone.

I frequently see the animal trainer having `no job` even though he has two animals to train. They've been stuck in a `Trained` state for a long while now. Do they have to be released from the chain to be trained further also?

Another odd point is that [the wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Hydra) says hydras are "Not trainable", but my hydra is marked as `Trained`, which adds to the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tamed creatures can be trained for work: Hunt and War trainind. I think wiki page mean that hydras cannot be trained for work.

Trainer will not retame creatures with `trained` state. You can't train wild creature to domesticated state, train will wear out eventually.

You can [tame child animals](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Animal_trainer#Taming_children), if you succeed in breeding your hydras.

Comment: I've three other questions based on what you've said: (1) Dogs and cats are have `(tame)` in their name. Does this mean domesticated? (2) Is `Trained` the max level of taming for wild animals? Anything further will require taming a child instead? (3) Can a trained giant cave spider create webbed cage traps or does this require a domesticated one?

Comment: A wild Giant Cave Spider is actually better for webbing your traps because they only shoot web at enemies, and you can more effectively control where their enemies are going to be when those enemies are you. The wiki has a whole page about farming silk from things like Giant Cave Spiders. http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Silk_farming

Comment: @gamecan, check wiki page linked in answer, it is pretty detailed 1) dogs and cats are domesticated by dwarfen civilization from start. You can check list of domesticated animal kinds in animals tab. 2) max level is `masterfully trained` (i don't know symbol to place here), as with any other item with quality levels. 3) I did not had experience with spiders yet. web has to lie over cage trap tile. Spider will only shoot webs at enemy, so tamed creature will ignore your dwarfes and animals.